# Storing part of nested JSON in backbone model

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have following JSON.

```
[
      {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "SecondName": "Steve",
        "Children":{  
                                 "results":[  
                                    {  
                                       "name":"Sue Anderson"
                                     },
                                     {  
                                        "name":"Jeff Anderson"
                                     },
                                     {  
                                        "name":"Mary Sanders"
                                     }

                                  ]
           }

      },

      {
        "FirstName": "gary",
        "SecondName": "Steve",
        "Children":{  
                                 "results":[  
                                    {  
                                       "name":"nick"
                                     },
                                     {  
                                        "name":"Jerry"
                                     },
                                     {  
                                        "name":"tom"
                                     }

                                  ]
           }

      }


]
```

I have a model specification in backbone to represent it.

```
var FamilyData= Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            FirstName: '',
            SecondName:'',
            Children:''
        }
    });
```

How Can I store that children part in the Model as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you want is for Children.results to be put in Children instead.

so add to your model a parse method override:

```
var FamilyData= Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            FirstName: '',
            SecondName:'',
            Children:''
        },
        parse: function(response) {
             response.Children = response.Children.results
             return response;
        }

    });
```

This should cause the resulting FamilyData.Children to contain what the JSON had in Children.results